Minimizing $\frac{ab+1}{a+b}+\frac{bc+1}{b+c}+\frac{ca+1}{c+a}$ for real $a,b,c$ such that $a+b+c=-1$ and $abc\le -3$

Let $a,b,c$ be real number such that $a+b+c=-1$ and $abc\le -3$. Find the minimum value of
$$\frac{ab+1}{a+b}+\frac{bc+1}{b+c}+\frac{ca+1}{c+a}$$

So, earlier this day I had a competition (it is called "MONOM", it is a Croatian competition).
This problem I couldn't quite solve, so I want to share my progress.
My progress:
First we observe that not all of the numbers $a,b,c$ can be negative. If they are, substituting $a=-x,b=-y,c=-z$, and  $x,y,z>0$. We get that
$$x+y+z=1$$
$$xyz\ge 3$$
But this is a contradiction using AM-GM, because
$$x+y+z\ge 3\sqrt[3]{xyz} \Longleftrightarrow xyz\le \frac{1}{27}$$
So, WLOG $a,b>0$ and $c<0$, so lets substitute $-c$ instead of $c$, so equivaletly we assume $c>0$.
We get
$ a+b-c=-1$ and  $abc\ge 3$.
Substituting $c=1+a+b$ at the end of the story we get
$$\frac{ab+1}{a+b}+a+b+\frac{b^2-1}{1+a}+\frac{a^2-1}{1+b}\ge\frac{ab}{a+b}+1+\frac{b^2-1}{1+a}+\frac{a^2-1}{1+b}$$
and
$$(a+1)(b+1)\ge 2\sqrt{3}$$
and I have no idea what to do from here. I hope this helps!

Honestly I first thought about adding $1$ to each term and then after all the algebra I got $$-(\frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{c+1}+\frac{(b+1)(c+1)}{a+1}+\frac{(c+1)(a+1)}{b+1})$$

Ok one hint : u are only thinking of am-gm here but it's actually am-gm-hm that will help

One more thing, it's a good practice to assume "wlog" but it should actually be $ a \ge b \ge 0$ and $c < 0$ for lesser confusion now apply am gm hm

Not exactly i thought of doing splitting the given expression into $\frac{ab}{a+b} + \frac{bc}{b+c} + \frac{ca}{c + a} + \frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{b+c} + \frac{1}{c+a}$ then applying am-gm-hm separately on first three and last three

@Ash_Blanc It's not immediately clear to me how you could make that work, because 1/ Equality doesn't hold when those expressions are equal, and 2/ Those expressions could be negative, so you can't AM-GM-HM. Can you elaborate further?

Proceeding along OP's lines
(Assume that $a, b > 0$ and $c < 0$.)
We have $c = -1 - a - b$.
From $abc = ab(-1-a-b) \le -3$, we have
$ab(1 + a + b) \ge 3$.
Using $ab \le (a + b)^2/4$, we have
$\frac14(a+b)^2(1 + a + b) \ge 3$
which results in $a + b \ge 2$.
We have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{ab+1}{a+b}+\frac{bc+1}{b+c}+\frac{ca+1}{c+a}
 &= \frac{ab+1}{a+b}+ a + b + \frac{b^2 - 1}{1 + a}+\frac{a^2 - 1}{1 + b}\\
 &\ge \frac{ab+1}{a+b}+ a + b + \frac{a^2 - 1}{1 + a}+\frac{b^2 - 1}{1 + b}\\
 &= \frac{ab+1}{a+b} + 2(a + b) -2 \\
 &\ge \frac{\frac{3}{1 + a + b}+1}{a+b} + 2(a + b) -2\\
 &\ge 3
\end{align*}
where we use the rearrangement inequality to obtain $ \frac{b^2 - 1}{1 + a}+\frac{a^2 - 1}{1 + b} \ge \frac{a^2 - 1}{1 + a}+\frac{b^2 - 1}{1 + b}$,
and use $ab(1 + a + b)\ge 3$
to obtain $ab \ge \frac{3}{1 + a + b}$,
and use ($x := a + b \ge 2$ )
$$\frac{\frac{3}{1 + x}+1}{x} + 2x -2 \ge 3.$$

Thanks for the solution! I actually got 8/10 for some reason on this problem, probably because in the end I just guessed the minimum would be $3$ and found when it is achieved, I also got correctly that it would all come down to basically
$$1+4-2=3$$, so that is fortunate!

@Kokos The expression are symmetric. Usually we guess the extrema occur when two of the three variables are equal.

We need prove :  $$q=ab+bc+ca \le -5.$$
Assuming that : $$c=\min\{a,b,c\},abc<0  \Longrightarrow a+b+1=-c> 0 \Longrightarrow ab(-c)=ab(a+b+1) \ge 3 \Longrightarrow ab>0 .$$
$$ \Longrightarrow \frac{(a+b)^2(a+b+1)}{4}\ge ab(a+b+1) \ge 3  \Longrightarrow (a+b)^3+(a+b)^2-12 \ge 0 \Longrightarrow a+b \ge 2 \Longrightarrow a>0,b>0.$$
$$\bullet q=ab-(a+b+1)(a+b) \le \frac{(a+b)^2}{4}-(a+b+1)(a+b)=-5-\frac{3}{4}\left(a+b+\frac{10}{3} \right)\left(a+b-2\right) \le -5.$$
$$\bullet T= \sum \frac{ab+1}{a+b}=3+\frac{(ab+bc+ca-1)(ab+bc+ca+5)}{(a+b)(a+1)(b+1)} \ge 3 \Longrightarrow T_{min}=3 , at : (a=b=1;c=-3). $$
